# Unity how to access components in a class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a character class with many variables, I made an RPG long ago in which I had a method to equip gear and unequip it, adding and subtracting values, pretty simple, I would:

```
public void equip(Gear g){
    increaseValues(g.getValue());
    //increaseValues..
}

public void unequip(Gear g){
    increaseValues(-g.getValue());
    //increaseValues..
}
```

Pretty basic, I could do the same in Unity but here is where the problem comes, in OOP I would create a class with values and methods but the trend in unity is to create scripts and add them as components to another class, thus I have no idea how to access the information on an object embedded component, what do I pass in the parameters? I tried GameObject but it tells me that the values or methods I'm trying to access do not exist within such object.

Comment: It sounds like you need to consult the basic Unity tutorials - a `GameObject` is the main entity, scripts are attached as components to it

Comment: Indeed, and not just basic ones, I could go through the whole documentation and never ask a thing in here, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Please note that posters here are not just male in gender. Some of our female helpers have expressed the opinion that every time they see references to a "gentlemen" audience, they feel excluded. Therefore, please try to avoid using this sort of address, or indeed any gendered language. Thanks.

Comment: Are you kidding me? a SJW with that score? omfg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access other `GameObject`'s scripts via `GameObject.GetComponent(Type type)` method.

```
public GameObject myGameObject; //Attach gameobject in Unity Editor
private MyClass myGameObjectClass;

void Start() {
    myGameObjectClass = myGameObject.GetComponent<MyClass>();
    //or you could use this
    //myGameObjectClass = myGameObject.GetComponent(typeof(MyClass)) as MyClass;
    myGameObjectClass.MyProperty = 2;
    myGameObjectClass.MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: You should always check the return value of `GetComponent` as it will return `null` if the gameobject doesn't have a component of the desired type